# Embedding with SWF in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, embedding

I am currently using flowplayer to stream videos in my application.I want to use swf because JS is not an option in my application.JS is striped by default for privacy reasons

Here is how i do it with flowplayer

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" data="/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"URL goes here", "plugins": {"controls": {"autoHide" : false} }}' />
```

My reason for the switch is because i want to use the HD toggle feature that JwPlayer provides.I couldn't find any swf equivalent for the JS below on JWPlayer site

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4"
      }]
    });
</script>
```

How can i convert the flowplayer embed code to JWplayer with HD toggle feature.I tried different implementation using the`jwplayer.flash.swf` but none seems to working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW Player 6 can be embedded only using Javascript. There is no implementation of it that can be done with the SWF file by itself.

Comment: it is possible with JW5 and does it has the HD toggle feature

Comment: It's true that the player.swf from JW5 could be embedded without JS, but JW5 is now very obsolete, and is completely unsupported. I believe it had the toggle feature, but I think it required a special HD plugin. But with the documentation now gone, it's almost impossible to figure out how to use it. And by dropping back to JW5, you'd be giving up all kinds of other things, like good HTML5 support. Blocking Javascript, but requiring Flash, is hardly a good trade-off.

Comment: Also remember that there's no Flash on any mobile device, no matter what script you use, so an SWF solution automatically eliminates anything other than desktops.

Comment: I use HTML5 with flash fallback on mobile but standard <video> tag isn't sexy

Comment: If you really want to look up embedding JW5, you can always find old support information on the old longtailvideo.com site using archive.org. Not recommended though.